# Обернуть все теги td в a

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно обернуть в table, в каждом теге tr все td в одну ссылку  . Как это можно сделать? Это необходимо чтобы вся информация индексировалась.
Если вешать onclick на tr - он не индексируется...

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: обернуть можно https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/26yL6tu4/, но это будет не валидная разметка

Comment: а если сделать так https://jsfiddle.net/gnuzn8f8/ ?

Comment: Таблицы в прошлом, есть блочная вёрстка и `display:table`

Comment: @kizoso, содержится: заменить `tr` на `a` и вместо таблицы использовать `div`ы с соответствующим `display`. Впрочем, мне это решение не очень нравится, поскольку всё-таки есть семантика. Но оно вполне решение и имеет право на существование.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ок, но все же больше похоже на комментарий

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr onclick="location.href='http://ссылка/';">
```

Comment: Такая ссылка не индексируется.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yuheyabawo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Lestalab, пример в jsbin как-то опровергает утверждение, что это не индексируется поисковиками?